# Dúvida em PHP conexão com banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou com uma dúvida em um código em PHP.

Meu código tá gerando vários alertas:

[image: Print dos erros]

E me parece que o mesmo não está fazendo conexão com o banco de dados, pois estou mandando ele imprimir alguns dados e ele não imprime nada na tela.

Vou colocar aqui trecho dos códigos:

```
<?php
$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Erro na conexão");
mysqli_select_db("painel_admin");
?>

<?php
session_start();
$usuariot = $_POST['usuario'];
$senhat = $_POST['senha']; 
include "conexao.php";

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario='$usuariot' AND senha='$senhat' LIMIT 1");
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if(empty($resultado)){
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header ("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: Cara, cada _warning_ tem uma mensagem. É só ler as mensagens e ver o que cada uma diz.

Comment: Passe a conexão como quarto argumento de `mysqli_connect()` depois não esqueça de passar a conexão como primeiro argumento em `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Seria isso:<?php
$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","painel_admin") or die ("Erro na conexão");
mysqli_select_db("painel_admin");
?>

Comment: Passa o nome do banco direto no `mysqli_connect`  : `$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "painel_admin");`

Comment: Deu certo passar direto no mysaqli_connect, OBRIGADO!!